# testing for empty/null string in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, null

I have a charfield with the following:

```
myString = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
```

In many of my objects, this particular string is often left blank, when created through the django admin interface. In MySQL, the column is VARCHAR(50) with default=NULL.

Whatever test I try to do in my views.py to detect blank values, always seems to evaluate to false whether the entry is blank or not:

```
myString is None
myString==""
len(myString)==0
```

How can I discriminate between blank and non-blank values for this field?

Thanks

EDIT:

Actual view is the following, I want to execute a block only if this field is not blank.

```
if myObject.myString:
     #do something
```

the block always executes, and I have tried all the above examples of testing for a blank field.

EDIT 2:

Scratch that, `if myObject.myString:` does indeed work.

Comment: `myString` is not a string -- it's a `models.CharField`. Show us your actual view where you're trying to do this.

Comment: so what does `print myString` or the equivalent show right before that `if` statement? You need to give us more info.

Comment: turns out the above does work, but needed to restart apache to get the altered code to execute. Oops.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

if your `d` is either `None` or `""` then simply check -

```
if d: 
    #do something
else:
    #do something else
```

Answer (score 13):

Some empty fields return empty strings while others return `None`. A nullable boolean field however, will return `False` when it has been set. This will not pass the test in Srikar's answer. A more robust solution is this:

```
if d in [None, '']:
    # This field is empty.
```

Answer (score 3):

`myString` is not a string -- it's a `models.CharField`. Show us your actual view where you're trying to do this.

If you've already got an instance of your model, you should just be able to do

```
if model_instance.myString:
```

to test if it's not blank.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where your variable is either None or '' (blank), you can just handle both of the conditions as follows

```
if my_string:
  # neither None nor blank
```